# What GRANT privileges are required to use %TYPE in variable declaration

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-grant

As `User1` I have the table:

```
CREATE TABLE USER1.test ( id NUMBER );
```

As `User2` I have the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USER2.passInATestId(
  in_id USER1.TEST.ID%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

However, this fails to compile with:

```
PLS-00201: identifier 'USER1.TEST' must be declared
```

If I grant the `REFERENCES` permissions

```
GRANT REFERENCES ON USER1.TEST TO USER2;
```

Then I get:

```
PLS-00904: insufficient privilege to access object USER1.TEST
```

If I grant the `SELECT` privilege then it will compile - however, `User2` can then perform selects on the table and I do not want them to do this directly. Is there a privilege I can use that allows me to reference the type of a column without also granting the ability to `SELECT` from the table?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You will have to use `in_id number` as the parameter definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a `SUBTYPE` in a package owned by `USER1`:

```
CREATE PACKAGE USER1.TYPE_DEFINITIONS
AS
  SUBTYPE TYPE__TEST__ID IS USER1.TEST.ID%TYPE;
END;
/
```

Then:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON USER1.TYPE_DEFINITIONS TO USER2;
```

The procedure can then be rewritten as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USER2.passInATestId(
  in_id USER1.TYPE_DEFINITIONS.TYPE__TEST__ID
)
IS
BEGIN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

I would prefer a solution that allows a declaration of the variable's type to directly reference the column's type rather than going through a level of indirection (but that does not seem to be possible).